# Jquery - clone selectmenu in table

Tags: jquery, user-interface, select, clone

I can't seem to figure this out...

I have a table with 'x' rows. When I click on a button I want to clone the last table row and append it behind it. So far no problem. But I have a select (using selectmenu styling) in every table row.

I have made a quick example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/u8Lpe/

When you click on 'Add table row' you can't select an option on the new added row. (it will just change the value of the row that's cloned)

I have searched and tried a lot of different things, but so far I haven't been able to fix it. (using refresh/destroy options etc.)

Hopefully someone can help me out, or has an idea what to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were couple of issues in your code. For the first row which you render along with page markup you apply `selectmenu` plugin on the select element inside it. `selectmenu` attaches few events and styles on it along with few extra markup.

When you clone(passing true as argument) the `tbody` which contains this select element with `selectmenu` plugin applied, everything is cloned. The `true` arguments tells jQuery to clone the events also applied on the elements, which is not required.

What you have to do is `clone` by passing `false` and after clone remove the extra `span` and inline style which the plugin adds and then call `selectmenu` on the new row select element.

I have fixed this in your fiddle take a look.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/u8Lpe/3/)**

Comment: Cheers! Works perfectly, thanks a lot. For those who have a similair issue, notice the there is still 'true' instead of 'false' in the demo above. Also I had to use div instead of span for some reason.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are cloning an element that has an ID (this is bad, as IDs should be unique). You should change the ID before you reinsert it into the DOM. At the same time you can make the new element a selectmenu.

Comment: You're right, that's pretty bad. I guess I should change it to a class instead. But even than it doesn't solve the problem (http://jsfiddle.net/u8Lpe/2/), can you give an example what I should do to make it work? (I'm not a pro in this) Thanks again.